# Facing problem while running eclipse,is the desktop entry correct?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, eclipse

I have created a desktop entry for running eclipse .

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=Eclipse 4
    Type=Application
    Exec=/home/shubhendu/eclipse/eclipse/eclipse
    Terminal=false
    Icon=/home/shubhendu/eclipse/eclipse/icon.xpm
    Comment=Integrated Development Environment
    NoDisplay=false
    Categories=Development;IDE;
    Name[en]=Eclipse
```

The eclipse opens but as soon as I select a project , it closes immediately.

Comment: Open a shell and navigate to the executable location and start it from there.  Note any informative messages in the shell during startup and at abnormal termination.  Find the log file at ".metadata/.log" in your workspace and report any significant error messages.

Answer (score 2):

As the application starts from the desktop entry you created, there is no issue with the desktop entry. This has to do something with the application itself. Try changing the `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true` so that you can see the logs when Eclipse shuts down. You might be able to pinpoint the exact cause there.